# Using Delegates and BeginInvoke with .NET 2.0 WebServices

Tags: .net, ajax, vb.net, asynchronous

I'm attempting to implement a simple long-polling/comet/reverse AJAX solution, and came across the concept of delegates, specifically with the `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` methods. I've built a Web Service that uses these concepts, but, having never used these, they make me a little nervous, and I have my doubts as to whether they are actually what I want.

The goal, of course, is to offload the actual processing from IIS processes onto other framework processes, for a reduction in server load when waiting on a long-poll request for data. I can't have gotten this right, but I want to know *why* and at least get some direction in *how it might be better accomplished* (not necessarily a solution, but maybe an article or some documentation).

The Web Service code:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class WebService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld() As String
        Dim threadId As Integer
        Dim thing As New Things
        Dim caller As New AsyncDoStuff(AddressOf thing.doStuff)
        Dim result As IAsyncResult = caller.BeginInvoke(3000, threadId, Nothing, Nothing)

        result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()

        Dim returnValue As String = caller.EndInvoke(threadId, result)

        result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close()

        Return returnValue
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Things
    Public Function doStuff(ByVal callDuration As Integer, <Out()> ByRef threadId As Integer) As String
        ' Imagine this method was accessing a database, looking for new information, and returning when it found some
        Thread.Sleep(callDuration)
        threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId()
        Return String.Format("My call time was {0}.", callDuration.ToString())
    End Function
End Class

Public Delegate Function AsyncDoStuff(ByVal callDuration As Integer, <Out()> ByRef threadID As Integer) As String
```

Comment: You've never used an event handler? `EventHandler` is just a delegate with a `(Object, EventArgs)` signature and no return value. You know delegates more than you think you do.

Comment: Wow. Blast from the past. I never actually got this implemented, opting instead for simple polling with increased intervals when no data was returned. I guess I never trusted myself with off-processes.

Answer (score 3):

[This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7050854/1188513) to the question "Is there a VB.NET equivalent of C# out parameters" is pretty clear:

> *No, there is no equivalent construct that allows a non-initialised variable to be passed to a method without a warning [...]*

However specifying the `<Out()>` attribute, despite being ignored by VB (`ByRef` is all you need, really), does allow a C# client to use it as an `out` parameter - so good call then!

---

Declaring the delegate at the bottom of the module, *after* it's being used, makes it uselessly confusing and prompts for unnecessary scrolling; I would have put it at the top... actually, I would have made the delegate a public member of the `WebService` class:

```
Public Class WebService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    Public Delegate Function AsyncDoStuff(ByVal callDuration As Integer, <Out()> ByRef threadID As Integer) As String

    '...
```

---

I very, very seldom declare my own delegate types, if at all. I don't like <s>`ref`</s> `ByRef` and <s>`out`</s> `<Out()>` parameters either - I think they should be avoided.

In this case I would have gone with a `Func<int,AsyncStuffResult>` (please excuse the C# notation), where the `int` parameter is the `callDuration`, and the `AsyncStuffResult` is a class that encapsulates everything you want to return from the function call - whatever that is.

This way if/when you need to return more things, your signature doesn't need to change, you only add new members to your result class - note that the `EventArgs` class fulfills the same goal.

```
Public Class AsyncStuffResult
    '- expose ThreadId as a get-only property
    '- expose your String result as a get-only property, too
    '- expose a constructor to assign the members
End Class
```

Comment: Death to delegates!!!